# chartboost integration iOS, small confusion

Tags: ios, appdelegate, chartboost

I've just successfully integrated test ads showing at GameOver screen. On the Chartboost integration website it states:

Best Practices
First run experience

It's good practice (and noted in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines) to show interstitials only after the user has played your game for the first time.

You can use the below Chartboost SDK delegate method to prevent interstitials until the second initialization call:

```
// For Chartboost SDKs v5.0+:

[Chartboost setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession:NO]

// For older Chartboost SDKs:
 - (BOOL)shouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession {
return NO;
}
```

I don't understand WHERE to place...

```
   [Chartboost setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession:NO]
```

Do I place it in AppDelegate.m within...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
  [Chartboost setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession:NO]
}
```

I looked at the chartboost Example project and it's not anywhere. So I don't know where to place the above code. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put that call immediately after initializing SDK

Use the below link for reference

https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201382909-6-x-Upgrade-Guide-iOS